# Qt-Designer forces lower case "#include <filename>", preventing Linux builds

Tags: qt

Qt-Designer. Promote a widget to a custom class. The class appears correctly in *.ui file. "MyClassName". The class appears correctly in the Qt-Designed object inspector "MyClassName". However, when building, a generated ui_xxxxxxx.h files has "#include " where the filename is forced to lower case.

This works for windows and mac but fails in the more strict Linux.

How can I force it to put in the correct case for the class?
I truly don't want to rename my *.h files to be lower case...

un-checking the option "lower case filenames" in the options|c++|file naming pane doesn't help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the class promotion dialog there are two fields towards the bottom, one for the class name and one for the header file. You just need to edit the header file entry to match the case of your header file that you want it to #include (when you type in the class name it auto-populates the header file entry with lower case).

Comment: For others that don't know where that dialog is, go to the `.ui` file, right-click the desired object in the right sidebar and select the `Promote to ...` menu item.

Comment: With some difference on QtCreator dialog (now using QT 5.14), but this problem is still solved with this solution!